# Как выполнить UPDATE в mysql циклом foreach php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

Есть массив, нужно значениями из массива проапдейтить значения из БД. Пробовал сделать так:

```
    foreach ($IDs_array as $user_index) {
            $sql2 = "UPDATE Users SET sendStatus='$user_index' WHERE deliveryTime='$send_date'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                        echo "OK<br>";
                        } 
            else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
}
```

Данные обновляются, но берется первое значение из массива и им обновляются все значения в столбце sendStatus.

Comment: скорее всего последнее значение берется, а где у вас объявление переменной $send_date ?

Comment: $send_date объявлена еще до foreach.

Comment: ну так смотрите что вы делаете, у вас в цикле есть несколько статусов и вы по очереди их обновляете, к примеру $IDs_array = ['send', 'error'] вы циклом меняете сначала статус на send а потом тем же записям меняете статус на error

Comment: иными словами, у вас условие апдейта не зависит от итерации цикла. поэтому каждый раз обновляются одни и те же записи. более того, обновляются по 2 раза на каждой итерации

Comment: @teran , а не подскажете, как составить цикл верно?

Comment: верно вам надо составить не цикл, а условие `where`

Comment: @teran добавил условие AND и все стало работать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Типипчный пример того, за что мы все так ненавидим Stack Overflow - бессмысленный вопрос, ещё более бессмысленный ответ, но зато заголовок, который попал гуглю в SEO. В итоге сотни людей приходят за ответом на вопрос как сделать апдейт в цикле, а видят какую-то галиматью.

Чтобы выполнить UPDATE в mysql циклом foreach в php надо использовать **подготовленные выражения** и **транзакции**. Чтобы использовать подготовленные выражения, надо

- подготовить запрос, поставив вместо всех переменных знаки вопроса
- привязать переменные к запросу функцией bind_param, где первым параметром идёт строка из букв "s", в которой количество букв равно количеству переменных, а дальше - сами переменные
- в цикле выполнять execute()

В сборе должно получиться примерно так:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET sendStatus=? WHERE deliveryTime=? and user_id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
/// три переменных - три буквы "s"
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $status, $send_date, $user_index);
$conn->begin_transaction();

foreach ($IDs_array as $user_index) {
     $stmt->execute();
}
$conn->commit();
```

получится быстро, надёжно и безопасно.

Перед этим не забыть [правильное соединение с mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect#oop), чтобы был включён режим вывода ошибок и установлена правильная кодировка.

Если данные для запроса приходят из цикла в виде массива, то проще всего переместить bind_param внутрь цикла

```
foreach ($data as  $row) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $status, $row['date'], $row['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

По всей видимости у вас вся проблема в переменной `send_date.` Проверьте как она создается и для чего переназначается (если она вообше нужна).